# Do not run Spring @Scheduled task on certain machine

Tags: java, spring, build-process, scheduled-tasks

Our web app has few scheduled tasks and we like this feature of Spring so much, many have started relying on it. We have a 'pilot' machine which shares the same configuration/db as prod machines. Since this machine points to the same db as prod machines, when it runs a scheduled task - it may affect prod data. Is there a way to not run Spring Scheduled task on this machine? We thought of relying on the machine name, but dont want to introduce a check each time a task starts. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

With Spring 3.1 Profiles it will be really easy, but here is a way you can do it in Spring 3.0.

In your context:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor" scheduler="configScheduler"/>
<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler"/>
<task:executor id="taskExecutor"/>
```

Use `@Bean` to define `configScheduler`, using a dummy scheduler if a system property `noScheduler` is set.

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig {
  @Resource(name="taskScheduler")
  ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler;

  @Bean
  ThreadPoolTaskScheduler configScheduler() {
      ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = 
        System.getProperty("noScheduler") == null : taskScheduler ?
          new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler() {
              @Override public ScheduledFuture schedule(Runnable task, Trigger trigger) { return null; }  // Cron
              @Override public ScheduledFuture scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, long period) { return null; }
              @Override public ScheduledFuture scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable task, long delay) { return null; }
          };

      return scheduler;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

With Spring 3.1, you'll get [profiles](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/), which might help you out.